# Question about using ML (xgboost) for timeseries

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, boosting

I want to train an ML model with 3 input parameters 1 output using Xgboost regressor. My output data is time-dependent meaning that I have the values of output parameters at 500 time steps. Also, I have 1000 measurements; this means that I have 1000 input values and 1000 output values data at each time step. Now, I can train my model in two ways:

1. Train an ML model for each time step separately. I have to do the training 500 times (for all time steps) and I have 1000 input and output values at each time step.
2. Considering time as an additional input to the problem, and train the whole model once for all time steps. This way I have 500000 (500*1000) input and output values and I need to train the ML model once.

I am not sure which method is the best. Any suggestions in this regard? Do they have any preferences in comparison to each other at all? Any reference where I can read more about this?

Comment: It's going to depend, in part, on whether there's any relationship between the measurements at different time periods, e.g., some sort of smoothness in the time series, or whether they are completely independent of each other, so that "time" is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jbowman. In fact, outputs are dependent on time; outputs are different at each time step. But we do not know the exact relation between the outputs and the time steps.

Comment: It depends a lot on what are you trying to predict? Future values given only information from the past (typical forecasting problem)? Or are you trying to predict missing in-between values in a time series (kind of filling in missing values/blanks)? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Björn. In fact, future values are not related to past values. So, the outputs change with time, but the values at each time step are not related to the values of the previous time step. Also, my time steps are fine enough and I do not need to predict the responses for values between them. Also, I am not interested in estimating values out of my time range.

Comment: Well, if values are completely unrelated over time (that's an unusual scenario to me, but I don't know anything about your application, because in every problem I've ever worked on, past values are strong predictors of future values), then I don't see that the time series nature of the problem would matter, at all, for what you do.